# When swapping hierarchy column with checkbox column, the grid UI is missing a column line which should show up

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am swapping the hierarchy column with a checkbox column, here is what the UI looks like after swapping the tow columns, as you can see the column that holds the hierarchy column cell is missing its column line, and I think that it has to do with the other grid inside the detail row, any idea on what is going wrong with the UI?

[image]

```js
jQuery.fn.swapWith = function(to) {
  return this.each(function() {
    var copy_to = $(to).clone(true);
    var copy_from = $(this).clone(true);
    $(to).replaceWith(copy_from);
    $(this).replaceWith(copy_to);
  });
};
$(document).ready(() => {
  LoadGrid();
});

function LoadGrid() {
  $("#Grid").empty();

  $("#Grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: {
      data: junkData
    },
    schema: {
      model: {
        id: "ClientID",
        fields: {
          ClientID: {
            type: "number",
            editable: false,
            hidden: true
          },
          AddressID: {
            type: "number",
            editable: false,
            hidden: true
          },
          FirstName: {
            type: "string",
            editable: true,
            hidden: false
          },
          LastName: {
            type: "string",
            editable: true,
            hidden: false
          },
          City: {
            type: "string",
            editable: true,
            hidden: false
          }
        }
      }
    },
    scrollable: true,
    columns: [{
        field: "ClientID",
        title: "ClientID",
        hidden: true
      },
      {
        field: "AddressID",
        title: "AddressID",
        hidden: true
      },
      {
        title: "",
        template: '<input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" />',
        lockable: false,
        width: "30px"
      },
      {
        field: "FirstName",
        title: "First Name",
        width: 350,
        lockable: false
      },
      {
        field: "LastName",
        title: "Last Name"
      },
      {
        field: "City",
        title: "City",
        attributes: {
          style: "overflow: hidden !important;text-overflow: ellipsis;white-space: nowrap;",
        }
      }
    ],
    change: function(e) {
      // Doing stuff
    },
    pageable: false,
    selectable: "row",
    dataBound: function(e) {
      // doing stuff
      this.thead.find('.k-hierarchy-cell').each(function(_, x) {
        x = $(x);
        x.swapWith($("th:eq(2)"));
      });

      this.tbody.find('.k-hierarchy-cell').each(function(_, x) {
        x = $(x);
        x.swapWith(x.closest("tr").find('td:eq(3)'));
      });

    },
    detailTemplate: kendo.template($("#detailTemplate").html()),
    detailInit: detailClientGrid,
    detailExpand: function(e) {
      //Collapse all row before exapnd current selected row
      e.sender.select(e.detailRow.prev());
      e.sender.collapseRow(e.sender.tbody.find('> tr.k-master-row').not(e.masterRow));
    },
    detailCollapse: function(e) {
      // Doing stuff
    }
  }).data("kendoGrid");
}

function detailClientGrid(e) {
  let masterRow, globalID, isOnImage, detailRow;
  masterRow = e.masterRow;
  ClientID = e.data.ClientID;
  detailRow = e.detailRow;

  $("<div class='client-options'/>").appendTo(e.detailCell).kendoGrid({
    dataSource: {
      data: moreJunkData,
      pageSize: 100,
      schema: {
        model: {
          id: "ColorID",
          fields: {
            ColorID: {
              type: "number"
            },
            ColorName: {
              type: "string"
            },
            BoxName: {
              type: "string"
            },
            BrandName: {
              type: "string"
            },
            Country: {
              type: "string"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    pageable: {
      refresh: true,
      pageSizes: true,
      buttonCount: 5
    },
    scrollable: false,
    selectable: "row",
    filterable: {
      mode: "row"
    },
    change: function(e) {
      // Doing stuff
    },
    columns: [{
        field: "ColorID",
        title: "Color ID",
        hidden: true
      },
      {
        field: "ColorName",
        title: "Color Name",
        filterable: {
          cell: {
            showOperators: false,
            operator: "contains"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        field: "BoxName",
        title: "Box Name"
      },
      {
        field: "BrandName",
        title: "Brand Name"
      },
      {
        field: "Country",
        title: "Country"
      }
    ],
    dataBound: function(e) {
      // Doing stuff
    }
  });
}
const junkData = [{
    ClientID: 1,
    AddressID: 3,
    FirstName: "John",
    LastName: "Smith",
    City: "Toronto"
  },
  {
    ClientID: 2,
    AddressID: 4,
    FirstName: "Jane",
    LastName: "Smith",
    City: "Ottawa"
  }
];

const moreJunkData = [{
    ColorID: 100,
    ColorName: "Blue",
    BoxName: "A",
    BrandName: "D",
    Country: "G"
  },
  {
    ColorID: 101,
    ColorName: "Red",
    BoxName: "B",
    BrandName: "E",
    Country: "H"
  },
  {
    ColorID: 102,
    ColorName: "Purple",
    BoxName: "C",
    BrandName: "F",
    Country: "I"
  }
];
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.3.1017/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.3.1017/styles/kendo.common-bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.3.1017/styles/kendo.bootstrap.min.css" />
<div id="container">
  <div id="GridWrapper">
    <div id="Grid">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="detailTemplate">
  <div>
    <div class="input-group" style="margin-top:2px;">
      <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></span>
      <input class="form-control search-options" style="width:295px; height:28px">
    </div>
  </div>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just tweak the cell style like this:

```
.k-hierarchy-cell {
  border-right: 1px solid #CCC;
}
```